# Character limit on dropdown list

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I have a list customized using InfoPath, The list has a dropdown list when the user selects this dropdown list, it brings huge data from an external list/data source and populated in this dropdown list. As we know drop-down list character limit is 255 and users are not able to submit the form. Is there anyone worked around this?
Is that possible to cut/limit 255 characters in this dropdown after a user selects from a drop-down field?
Thanks, 
Gashaye

Answer (score 0):

Gashaye,

You have two options.

1. Use a substring function to limit the characters in the drop-down
2. Convert the drop-down to a multi-line text field that allows for more characters.

[Drop down list to multiple of text maximizing 255 characters](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8160c9f-aa7d-42af-ae5c-19c9627e4a78/drop-down-list-to-multiple-of-text-maximizing-255-characters?forum=sharepointadmin)

[Text Formula like substring (InfoPath)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9f8764a-25e2-4d62-bf5b-889951f72e71/text-formula-like-substring-infopath?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)